# ASP.NET Caching appears to be very limited after Windows Creators Update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm not sure I have a specific question other than--have other people seen this?  And if so, is there a known workaround / fix?  I have failed to find anything on Google on this topic.

Basically, we have an ASP.NET MVC application that we run on localhost that extensively uses the ASP.NET in memory cache.  We cache many repeated requests to the Db.

Yesterday, we upgraded two of our dev machines to Windows 10 Creators Update.  After that update, we noticed that the page requests on just those machines started to craw.  Upwards of 30 seconds per page.

After some debugging and viewing logs, we are seeing that the system is making the same request to the Db 200-300 times per request.  Previously, this would just be cached the first time, and that request would not happen again until the cache expired it.

What we are seeing is that this code:

```
var myObject = LoadSomethingFromDb();
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("test", myObject);
var test = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("test");
```

at some point, the Get would be returning NULL even if it is right after the Insert in code and even though there is no way the cache is even close to full.  The application is just starting.

Anybody else see this?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  We got bit by the Absolute Cache Expiration parameter which I neglected to include in the question's code because I didn't think that was relevant.

We were using an absolute cache expiration of:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60)
```

instead, we should have been using:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60)
```

Not sure why the former was fine in Windows prior to Creator's Update, but the change to UtcNow seems to make the cache work again.

Comment: I am with the same problem. Before Creator's Update if I use Now works fine, after Creator's Update I need to use UtcNow to works. The problem is that if I change to UtcNow and run the code before update the cache will be alive more time that I want. For example, my zone time is -3 GMT, so if I use DateTime.UtcNow.AddHour(1) before update, the cache will be alive 4 hours intead of 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that after the windows creators update that the behavior of cache.Insert overload methods behave differently.

```
        [Test]
    public void CanDemonstrateCacheExpirationInconsistency()
    {
        var cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var key1 =$"Now{now.Ticks}";
        var key2 = key1+"2";
        var key3 = $"UtcNow{now.Ticks}";
        var key4 = key3 + "2";
        cache.Insert(key1, true, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        cache.Insert(key2, true, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,CacheItemPriority.Default,null);
        cache.Insert(key3, true, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        cache.Insert(key4, true, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);

        Assert.That(cache.Get(key1), Is.Null); //Using this overload with datetime.now expires the cache immediately
        Assert.That(cache.Get(key2), Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(cache.Get(key3), Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(cache.Get(key4), Is.Not.Null);
    }
```